# How can I get reflection building project and created new class file in project via custom Gradle plugin?

Tags: groovy, gradle

### I have two method in my custom Gradle plugin:

1. First method (by name createClasss) should create new class file in src building project
2. Second method (by name getAllClass) should get reflection var building project and subproject

How to do it with the help of the existing variable project?

```
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("runMyPlugin") << {
            createClass(project)
            getAllClass(project)
        }
    }

    void createClass(Project project) {
        //In this block need create new class file in src building project
    }

    void getAllClass(Project project) {
        //In this method needed get reflection var building project and subproject
        String packageName
        def reflections = new Reflections(packageName)
    }
}
```